# CanCan Incorrectly Denying Admin Access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm working with someone else's code plus I'm rather inexperienced with Rails and i'm having an issue with CanCan & Devise.

When trying to login (using credentials I know are there as they previously worked and I've checked the DB and successfully used the reset function) I get an error screen stating.

```
CanCan::AccessDenied in AdminController#index

You are not authorized to access this page.

app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:4:in `index'
config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

and in the terminal

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-14 13:13:01 +0000
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"T8CJkCIEA3r7ROiknVp/vbEgeKCBZEjl3uYd+46G7no=", "user"=>{"email"=>"pass@user.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'pass@user.com' LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2012-11-14 11:10:56', `current_sign_in_at` = '2012-11-14 13:13:01', `sign_in_count` = 219, `updated_at` = '2012-11-14 13:13:01' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
(0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://core.lvh.me:3000/admin
Completed 302 Found in 355ms


Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-14 13:13:02 +0000
  Processing by AdminController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 265ms

CanCan::AccessDenied (You are not authorized to access this page.):
  app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:4:in `index'
  config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

admin_controller.rb

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  def index
   authorize! :index, :admin (#line 4)
  end
```

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    case user.role_name

    when "super_admin"
      # can do everything
      can :manage, :all

    when "franchise_admin"
      can [:read, :search, :all, :up_down_index], Article
      can [:old_feed, :sites, :new_feed], MobileFeed
      can [:new, :read, :update], SiteSpecificArticle, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:index, :new_site_essentials], :admin


    when "franchise_editor"
      can [:new, :read, :update], SiteSpecificArticle { |ssa| ssa.site.customer.sites.include?(user.site) }
      can [:old_feed, :sites, :new_feed], MobileFeed
      can [:read, :search, :all, :up_down_index], Article

    when "site_admin"
      # can CRUD users for their site
      can :manage, User, site_id: user.site_id
      # can edit content for their site
      can [:read, :update], ArticleSitePermission, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:read, :update], CoreArticleSiteVisibility, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:new, :read, :update], SiteSpecificArticle, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:new, :read, :update], FrontPageCampaign, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:new, :read, :update], FrontPageTimeBasedArticle, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:new, :read, :update], FrontpageArticle, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:index, :new_site_essentials], :admin
      can [:read, :search, :all, :up_down_index, :hidden_in_this_site], Article
      can [:old_feed, :sites, :new_feed], MobileFeed
      can [:index, :create], TrackMood
      can :site_styles, Site

    when "editor"
      # can edit content for their site
      can [:read, :update], ArticleSitePermission, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:read, :update], CoreArticleSiteVisibility, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:new, :read, :update], SiteSpecificArticle, site_id: user.site_id
      can :manage, FrontPageCampaign, site_id: user.site_id
      can :manage, User, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:new, :read, :update], FrontPageTimeBasedArticle, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:new, :read, :update], FrontpageArticle, site_id: user.site_id
      can [:old_feed, :sites, :new_feed], MobileFeed
      can [:index, :new_site_essentials], :admin
      can [:read, :search, :all, :up_down_index, :hidden_in_this_site], Article
      can [:index, :create], TrackMood
      can :site_styles, Site

    else
      # guest user (not logged in)
      can [:read, :search, :up_down_index], Article
      can [:old_feed, :sites, :new_feed], MobileFeed
      can [:index, :create], TrackMood
      can :site_styles, Site
    end
  end
end
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Even if it is just another step in trying to debug the issue.

Thank you

Comment: Please post your ability.rb so we can see how your are authorizing the profiles

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a role named "admin" -- there's super_admin, franchise_admin, site_admin, etc.  Try replacing `:admin` with `:super_admin` in the controller#index method.

Comment: what role user of your account which you used to log in?

Comment: the one I am trying IS a super_user. It seems that it is failing to actually log in. any suggestions on debugging why the login is failing?

Comment: @edwardgd i don't see any role name is `super_user` in `ability.rb`, just has `super_admin`. You should use an account user has role name is `super_admin`.

Comment: You could think about doing the following `# raise user.role_name?(:super_admin).inspect` and check what the output of this is. Also do you have some sort of `role?` method defined in your user model?

Answer (score 3):

The CanCan wiki on Github states that:

"Adding authorize_resource will make a before filter which calls authorize!, passing the resource instance variable if it exists. If the instance variable isn't set (such as in the index action) it will pass in the class name. For example, if we have a ProductsController it will do this before each action."

```
authorize!(params[:action], @product || Product)
```

Your problem is that you're trying to authorize the :index action of the :admin symbol, when you actually have to authorize the admin object or model, like this:

```
authorize!(:index, @admin)
```

I think you misunderstood the authorize! method and tried to authorize the index action for the role :admin, but all the CanCan stuff is authorized based on the current_ability, which is supposed to be the first thing set on the user session adter the login. CanCan kind of does this for you, with this default ApplicationController method:

```
def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
end
```

But this means you need to have another method called current_user that returns the current user (doh). Check if you have this set up, if not then set it up and change :admin to @admin (which you have to instantiate, I think is something like `current_user.admin`(?) ).

One more thing: if you're doing the authorization like this just for debug, ok, no problem, but if you're thinking in actually authorize every action mannualy like this, please don't. CanCan have a method called `load_and_authorize_resource`, that both authorizes the current_user for every action of the controller and also instantiates the variable @model, for example @products, to: `Product.accessible_by(current_ability)`. This works very well when you have something that the user can only see or manage in some cases, like editing their own profile. Of course you have to setup this in the ability.rb file. This method goes like this:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

    load_and_authorize_resource

    def index
        # @admins here will have every admin that the user can see
    end

end
```

And if you have some action that you don't need to be authorized, you can say:

```
load_and_authorize_resource, :only => [:action1, :action2]
load_and_authorize_resource, :except => [:action1, :action2]
```

Or also:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
skip_authorize_resource, :only => [:action1]
skip_authorize_resource, :except => :action2 #can be both an array or single symbol
```

I hope this helps you and anyone also having this problem :)

Comment: wow cheers for the info. Not working on this again until tomorrow but will try put it into practice then and give and update. Thanks again for the verbose response

Comment: Hi. I am still having issues with this. I think it may be something to do with checking that the user is in the correct location. Just because on other pages which change when logged in, there is still no obvious change. so it is not just an issue with accessing restricted areas, but common pages that change due to logged in status

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing to:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  def index
    authorize! :index, :super_admin (#line 4)
  end
```

Comment: sadly I can only put bits up as this project is private :-(